# How to send an email to a local email server using python requests

Tags: python, network-programming, python-requests, pop3

I've set up a local email server as described here:

https://gist.github.com/raelgc/6031274

Im using the following python code to try to send an email:

```
import requests
requests.post('http://localhost.com')
```

I get the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0c75631f10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

I've tried disabling the firewall (`sudo ufw disable`), specifying pop3 and IMAP ports and using difference schemes but I continue to get this error.

I suspect this is perhaps because `requests` only supports http. If so then how do I achieve sending an email with `requests`.

Comment: `requests.post('http://localhost.com')` - is that a full line of code?

Comment: Yes, I've removed all other parameters, since they don't affect the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix is a mailserver and uses TCP ports 25, 465 and 587. It uses SMTP to communicate and as far as I know there is no API interface available. If you want to send e-mail you need smtplib, requests will not work.

A python smtplib example with a postfix server: 
http://masnun.com/2010/01/01/sending-mail-via-postfix-a-perfect-python-example.html